# React HOC class returns nothing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am facing a problem I can't figure out. For a project we use React to generate a layout from JSON input using the following code (simplified):

```
function generateComponents(children, params) {
  let comps = [];
  if (!children || children && children.length === 0) {
    return [];
  }

  forEach(children, (comp) => {
      let compName = comp.component;
      let createdComp;
      switch (compName) {
        case 'test1':
          createdComp = TestOne(Object.assign({}, comp, params));
          break;
        case 'test2':
          createdComp = TestTwo(Object.assign({}, comp, params));
          break;
      }
      comps.push(createdComp)
    }
  }
  return comps.length === 1 ? comps[0] : comps;
}
```

This works well and the layout is generated correctly. We wanted to take this a step further and wrap the `createdComp` in a `Higher Order Component`. We implemented that in the following way:

```
function generateComponents(children, params) {
  // see above for implementation

  let component;

  if (condition)
    component = testingHOC(createdComp);
  else
    component = createdComp

  comps.push(component);
}

// TestingHOC.js
export function testingHoc(WrappedComponent) {
  console.log('wrapped')
  return class TestingHoc extends Component {
    render() {
      console.log('props TestingHOC', this.props);
      return ( <WrappedComponent { ...this.props} />);
    }
  }
};
```

This broke our component generation. The code returns nothing. The only thing that gets logged is the `console.log('wrapped')`, the render function of the class is never called. What are we missing here?

***EDIT:***
Render method of the render class:

```
render() {
    const children = this.state.children;
    const {params} = this.props;
    const arrChildren = isArray(children) ? children : [children];
    let comps = generateComponents(arrChildren, params || {});
    if (isArray(comps)) {
        return (
            <ViewComponent>
                {comps}
            </ViewComponent>
        );
    } else {
        return comps;
    }
}
```

***EDIT 2:***

Console.log of `{comps}` with the testingHoc
[image: Console.log of <code>{comps}</code> with the testingHoc]
Console.log of `{comps}` **without** the testingHoc
[image: Desired state of children]

***Edit 3***

Added the code for ViewComponent:

```
import React from 'react';

const ViewComponent = (props) => (
    <div {...props}/>
);

export default ViewComponent;
```

Comment: where do you render the generated components?

Comment: @lustoykov Added the render method

Comment: "The code returns nothing." means that `generateComponents` returns `undefined` or `null`?

Comment: Are you actually rendering the children of `ViewComponent`? Does `comps` actually have any components in it? Show the `ViewComponent` render method.

Comment: @IzumiSy maybe returns nothing is the wrong terminology. By that I mean the code never reaches the class. The code reaches the testingHoc function, but never instantiates the class it seems.

Comment: @martin-dawson Comps are actually rendered, I have attached a console.log of { comps } with and without the component being wrapped in testingHoc.

Comment: You are not returning comps from your `generateComponents` function. Was this deliberate ?

Comment: Can I see implemention of `ViewComponent`? That would be a clue.

Comment: @Prasanna Actually, the returning happens after the foreach, I added that in the code, sorry for that

Comment: @IzumiSy I added the code for the ViewComponent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue you are facing is because of the inherent difference between a [React element and a React component.](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html)

When you are not using the HOC, you are creating a React element which can be seen by the first console.log image. This is the output after [reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html#top-down-reconciliation) has occurred.

When you use the HOC, your HOC returns a component which shows up as the `test(props)` function in your second console.log image.

To have the same functionality with your HOC enhanced components, you need to change the code in `generateComponents` functions to

```
  if (condition){
     let Comp = testingHOC(createdComp);
     component = <Comp/>;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the theory, I am going to look into that! The code return  'TypeError: Cannot call class as a function' however.

Comment: Can you please try the edited code and let me know what you get?

Comment: Or, in the same style as the initial implementation: `component = testingHOC(createdComp)()`

Comment: This actually works, thank you very much! But how come this works? And the original implementation does not?

Comment: In the original implementation, the `testingHOC` method was returning a component, which was stored in the `comps`  array and then the array was used in the render method. So the array contained components which had not been rendered and hence were not transformed into elements using reconciliation. When you assign `<Comp/>` to the array instead, it is the element that is being stored in the `comps` array, as can be seen from a console.log of `comps`, and hence it is rendered without issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation! This solves a lot for us, thanks again. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
    ...
    return (
        <ViewComponent>
            {comps.map((Comp) => <Comp />)}
        </ViewComponent>
    );
    ...
```

or

```
    ...
    return (
        <ViewComponent>
            {comps.map((comp) => comp())}
        </ViewComponent>
    );
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however the code returns an error now saying: 'TypeError: Cannot call class as a function' by both methods